# Trigger when a certain appointment is changed

Tags: triggers, exchange-server

Is there a way to trigger execution of code when a certain appointment is changed in Exchange?

I push into Exchange via EWS some appointments created from information stored in our application, and when any of these appointments is deleted or rescheduled, I want to execute my own actions (like, send out complaint emails or update the information in our application).

Can I somehow hook a trigger to these appointments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't scope it to specific appointments, but you can get notifications on the calendar. https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn458791(v=exchg.150).aspx